# Outside Link Useage

Tags: discussion, links

We should not allow links to outside Websites in either the questions or answers.  The idea is that WE are the destination site for users - it seems a bit lazy!!

Comment: Speaking of lazy!!  Just sayin'.

Comment: What's lazy about asking the question?

Comment: This seems against the spirit of the web, not to mention exclusionary. However, posting guidelines as to what types of links are appropriate sounds useful.

Comment: Answers: Short, concise with outside links used to provide additional information that might validate or elucidate upon the original point.  Does that sound like a fair recap?

Answer (score 13):

I disagree.

There might be additional related information in the question or an answer.

Also, you need reason to believe the information.  There's often a need to provide reference materials (eg, FDA guidelines, if nothing else).  We *do not* want people copy & pasting information and introducing plagiarism issues without correctly citing the source.

Answer (score 5):

Answers also need to be short and to the point.  I prefer to direct readers to more detailed answers and explanations elsewhere.  As Joe mentioned, it also helps validate the answer in the mind of the reader.